# setting SSLv2-only Apache web server

Tags: apache, server, virtual-machine, sslv2

I would like to setup an Apache web server (in a VM) which only supports **ONLY** SSLv2 SSLProtocol for testing purposes. Are there any instructions online for that, or could anyone guide me on that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

go to /conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf and find out following setting:

```
#   SSL Cipher Suite:
#   List the ciphers that the client is permitted to negotiate.
#   See the mod_ssl documentation for a complete list.
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
```

you can adjust the line started with SSLCipherSuite and select protocol you want to use.

Comment: this is for Ubuntu Apache server?

Comment: @freak_warrior You can find it in /etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: i got an error that 'sslv2 not supported by this version of openssl'...

Comment: @freak_warrior , I believe sslv2 has been deprecated in latest version due to weaknesses in the security of the protocol. You may have to look for old version of mod_ssl.

Comment: so which version of ubuntu server will have an older version of mod_ssl supporting sslv2?

Comment: @freak_warrior it's a matter of openssl, not ubuntu. 1) find out where your current openssl is. 2) follow this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/463301/how-to-install-apache-with-openssl-1-0-1 3) create a softlink to your current openssl